# 「Access violation at address～」と表示され処理できません

Tags: windows

下記Windows xp時代から利用されているLoaddata to DBのツールがあります。
実行ファイル名xxxxxx.exeで中身不明です。
長年にわたって使ったツールで多分プログラム自身は問題ないと思います。
処理内容は入力ファイルにあるデータをデータベースへアップロードです。

先日、Windows xpで'xxxxxx.exe'を実行しましたら、下記エラーが表示され処理ができません。
Access violation at address 0048DCBF in module 'xxxxxx.exe'.Read of addres 00000016.
４パターンで入力ファイル別で同じプログラムを使って別々のデータベースへデータアップロード処理を行います。
２パターン（２ＤＢ）処理正常で、２パターン（２ＤＢ）処理エラーでした。

メモリが不足したときに起こったと判断し、
Windows xpからEXEファイル、dllファイル、必要データをWindows 7へ移行しました。

Windows 7で'xxxxxx.exe'を実行しましたら、
Windows xpと同じパターンでエラーが表示され処理できません。
以前バックアップ取ったEXEファイル、dllファイルを入れ替えてもエラーが表示されます。

その後、ＰＣ最適化、エラーチェック、デフラグ、ウイルスチェックなどを行ってから、
一時的に治りましたが、また同じエラーで処理できません。
今回は３パターン（３ＤＢ）処理正常で、１パターン（１ＤＢ）処理エラーです。
またＰＣ最適化、エラーチェック、デフラグ、ウイルスチェックなどを行っても治りません。

プログラム処理でデータベースが破損されることになったら、Read of addres 00000016.
などのエラーは発生されますか？

プログラムソースはないので、デバックとかできません。
できるだけエラーを回避してそのツールを利用できればと思います。

どのように対応すれば教えていただけますか。

Comment: 第一義的にはそのプログラムに問題があるように思います。2義的には使い方が間違っている。プログラムで必要なファイルが壊れているあるいは無くなっているとかなのかなと思います。中身不明では探りようがないので、プログラムをインストールしなおすかこの際別のツールを利用するなどしてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: PC最適化やデフラグで症状が変わるのであれば、ハードディスク装置が劣化しているのかも知れません。壊れる前にハードディスクのバックアップを取るのが重要だと思います。そして、引越しツールなどで新しいハードディスクに古いハードディスクの内容を移してから、新しいハードディスクに差し替えて見てください。

Comment: 長年使って来てたとしても潜在バグはありますし、テストが不十分であれば設定ファイルなどの外部要因から想定されていない挙動を行い例外を吐くことは、普通にあることです。
まずは、使い方を調べる。設定ファイルなどの設定項目の意味を調べる。分からなければ、開発元に聞く。開発元が無ければ...どうにもならないと思います。提示されている情報を見るに、環境依存というよりは、そのアプリケーションのバグだと思われます。

Comment: ソースがあればデバッグして最新環境で再コンパイルですね。なければどうにもならないと思います！

Comment: 皆様コメントありがとうございます。ハードディスク不良、メモリ不足などは対応できます。アプリケーションのバグなら、何もできません。できることから試にやっていきます。進展がありましたら、報告します。

Answer (score 1):

エラーが発生した時点でデバッガーをアタッチすれば、原因個所がどこにあるかが判別できます。既にコメントが付いているように、おおよその場合において使用されているツールに問題があることが予想されます。

本来であれば、デバッグを行い修正すべきです。

---

それができない状況における質問だとは思います。その場合ですが、実行ファイルのプロパティの互換性タブで設定を行うことで、もしかすると動作するかもしれません。

---

それとは別の視点で、最終的には

> Read of addres 00000016.

でのエラーではありますが、このエラーに陥る前にヒープ破壊を引き起こしたためにデータ不正となっている可能性もあります。その場合ですが、何回か実行していると[フォールトトレラントヒープ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd744764(v=vs.85).aspx)によりヒープ破壊を回避するようにWindowsが振る舞うこともあります。

Comment: たくさんのコメント・ご回答ありがとうございます。
まず、「フォールトトレラントヒープ」を確認させていただきます。

Comment: フォールト トレラント ヒープイベントログを確認しましたが、特にエラー情報はありません。
実行ファイルのプロパティの互換性タブで「互換モードでこのプログラムを実行する」と「管理者としてこのプログラムを実行する」を設定して処理してみましたが、同じRead of addres 00000016.エラーが発生しました。

Comment: 最終に成功した時のデータベースのバックアップでＤＢを復元し、再処理で「Rea‌​d of addres 00000016.」エラーを回避できて無事に完了しました。やはりプログラム処理でデータベースが破損したと思います。スースはないから、それ以上検証はできません。
皆様有難うございました。